# Rating and Feedback Path datas to use in WPF User controls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, rating, feedback

i am new to WPF,in my WPF Application i want to place multiple Feed Back Controls like Rating in star,smiley and heart.in which we can configure no.of rating controls(eg:like 5 star) value of each rating,apart from the functionality part i didn't found any proper path data for the smile and heart paths.

can any one please help me on getting path data for these shapes..

Answer (score 0):

Try [Syncfusion's](https://www.syncfusion.com/) [MetroStudio](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio). Their path data's are royalty free.

Comment: How MetroStudio can help in getting the Path data of a smiley!!

Comment: Metro studio has 7000+ icon set, you can copy the path from application.